# Lookup previous values on condition in SQL Server 2017 using a table as a queue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

When looking up a row on a table called reason:

```
machine_id  reason   start_time
001234      moving   10:00:00
001234      parked   10:10:00
001234      moving   10:15:00
001234      NULL     10:20:00
001234      NULL     10:25:00
001234      dumping  10:30:00

009876      parked   10:00:00
009876      NULL     10:10:00
009876      NULL     10:15:00
009876      moving   10:20:00
009876      dumping  10:25:00
```

For any reason's with a NULL value I need to get the most recent value that wasn't NULL, so 001234 NULL values would both become 'moving', and 009876 NULL values would both become 'parked'.

I would normally solve this with a cross apply like:

```
SELECT 
    r1.machine_id    
    ,ISNULL(r1.reason,r2.reason) AS reason
    ,r1.start_time
FROM #reason r1
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1
            r2.reason
    FROM #reason r2
    WHERE r2.machine_oid = r1.machine_oid 
    AND r2.start_time < r1.start_time
    AND r2.reason IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY start_time DESC
) r2
```

But this table I'm querying is hundreds of thousands of rows (can't modify the source database) and the complexity of the query seems close to n^2.

In C++ I would solve by using a priority queue and discarding items from the list of objects to check that didn't meet the criteria so the complexity is closer to nlogn.

I tried understanding the post about using tables as queues here: http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues but it was beyond my skill level.

Because it's a very common requirement for my datasets, I was hoping there is an elegant solution that can be applied?

Comment: I just had an idea after posting this to break up the comparison tables into smaller chunks by joining date id's and only looking as far back as the day before. This has improved performance much closer to nlogn, but it would still be a lot better with a priority queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [machine_id] VARCHAR(6)
   ,[reason] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[start_time] TIME
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource([machine_id], [reason], [start_time])
VALUES ('001234', 'moving', '10:00:00')
      ,('001234', 'parked', '10:10:00')
      ,('001234', 'moving', '10:15:00')
      ,('001234', NULL, '10:20:00')
      ,('001234', NULL, '10:25:00')
      ,('001234', 'dumping', '10:30:00')
      ,('009876', 'parked', '10:00:00')
      ,('009876', NULL, '10:10:00')
      ,('009876', NULL, '10:15:00')
      ,('009876', 'moving', '10:20:00')
      ,('009876', 'dumping',  '10:25:00');


SELECT [machine_id]
      ,[reason] AS [reason_old]
      ,ISNULL([reason], MAX([Reason]) OVER (PARTITION BY [machine_id], [RowID])) AS [reason]
      ,[start_time]
FROM 
(
    SELECT *
          ,SUM(IIF([reason] IS NULL, 0, 1)) OVER (PARTITION BY [machine_id] ORDER BY [start_time] ASC) AS [RowID]
    FROM @DataSource 
) DS
ORDER BY [machine_id]
        ,[start_time];
```

[image]

The idea is to use `SUM` to group the records with `NULL` value with the the first record with `NOT NULL` value.

```
SELECT *
      ,SUM(IIF([reason] IS NULL, 0, 1)) OVER (PARTITION BY [machine_id] ORDER BY [start_time] ASC) AS [RowID]
FROM @DataSource;
```

[image]

Then, we can simply get the `MAX/MIN` value for such group as these aggregates ignore `NULL`s and will return the `NOT NULL` value.

Comment: This improved the performance for 300,000 rows from 15 minutes to 6 seconds! The complexity appears to have gone from n^2 to very close to nlogn. Thank you so much, I will be using this technique hundreds of more times on my datasets.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:
It will give you the values for the NULL for each machine_id

```
select a.* from reason a
inner join reason b on a.machine_id = b.machine_id 
and a.reason is not null and b.reason is null and a.start_time < b.start_time
where 
not exists(select 1 from reason c where a.machine_id = c.machine_id 
and a.start_time < c.start_time and c.start_time < b.start_time)
```